# Java Sun HttpServer not serving data

Tags: java, http, webserver, handler, httphandler

The following should serve some text at localhost:8080/
However, nothing seems to happen. It doesn't trigger any exceptions, compiles fine, doesn't crash, etc... But the handler is never called. I'm using mint Linux.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.*;

public class MyServer {
    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    public class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Request received.");
            String response = "<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>";
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            exchange.getResponseBody().write(response.getBytes());
            exchange.close();                
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    private HttpServer server;

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    public MyServer() throws IOException {
        server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 8080), 100);
        server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    public void start() {
        server.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {    
            System.out.println("Starting...");
            MyServer ms = new MyServer();
            ms.start();
            System.out.println("Started.");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "Nothing seems to happen"? Can you not make a TCP connection? Connection is closed? Don't get an HTTP response? HTTP error? 200 with empty response body?

Comment: Is TCP the default protocol? Typing http://localhost:8080 in a browser returns a message saying a connection could not be made.